# How to retrieve Max Date from a left outer join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables client_headquarter & clients

client_headquarter:
id

clients:
id, headquarterid, clentname, tscreated

I want to show all the headquarters and along with each headquarter show the "most recent" client (ts_created) if it exists else a blank in its place. I want it all to be sorted by headquarters that have no clients, older clients, and latest clients at the bottom.

Can someone assist with this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT client_headquarter.id, max(clients.tscreated)
FROM client_headquarter 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clients ON clients.headquarterid = client_headquarter.id
GROUP BY client_headquarter.id
ORDER BY MAX(clients.tscreated) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like..

```
> select chq.id, count(clientname), max(tscreated) from clients c
> left outer join client_headquarter chq on c.hearquarterid = chq.id
> group by chq.id
> order by count(clientname) DESC, max(tscreated) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    ch.id as [Headquarter ID],
    c.clientname as [Most Recent Client Name],
    c.tscreated as [Date Created]
from 
    client_headquarter ch
    left join 
    (select 
        headquarterid,
        max(tscreated)
    from
        clients
    group by
        headquarterid
    ) recent on recent.headquarterid = ch.id
    left join clients c on c.headquarterid = ch.headquarterid and c.tscreated = recent.tscreated
order by
    c.tscreated
```

This will create multiple rows for a single headquarter if multiple clients have the same created date. If this is not desirable, then some explicit means of distinguishing a winner will have to be defined and implemented.